# Como aumentar o numero de comentários no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de saber como posso aumentar o número de comentários que aparece no wordpress para moderação.

Obs.: não é o número de comentários do post não. É o da parte de administração, onde você pode aprovar, reprovar ou marcar como span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na página dos comentários, na parte superior à direita, tens um botão "Opções de ecrã" como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique neste botão e poderás mudar o número de comentários visualizados

Comment: Na tela de administração do WP aparecem apenas 20 comentários para aprovação. Teria como aumentar para 50 ou 100 comentários para aprovar/reprovar/marcar como spam de uma só vez?

Comment: Mas tens a certeza que existem mais de 20 comentários que aparecem?

Comment: editei a minha resposta. Vê a solução.